# Which activity called the adapter

Tags: android, adapter, baseadapter

I am using an adapter to populate a listview , 
I am using same adapter in 2 activities but I need to hide an element of the layout in one case and not in another .
So is there a way to figure out which activity called the adapter (in the adapter class ) ?

```
public class Db_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<db_list> mDataList;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

public Db_adapter(Context mContext, List<db_list> mDataList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
    this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position  ) {
    return mDataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dblayout,parent,false);
        viewHolder.tv_db_name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_db_name);
        viewHolder.tv_db_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_db_number);
        viewHolder.iv_delete = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    db_list rowData = mDataList.get(position);
    viewHolder.tv_db_name.setText(rowData.getDb_name());
    viewHolder.tv_db_number.setText(rowData.getDn_number());
    viewHolder.iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DeleteDb_async().execute(Add_deliveryBoy.db_id_list.get(position), String.valueOf(position));

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public void onDataSetChanged(List<db_list> mDataList) {
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView tv_db_name,tv_db_number;
    private ImageView iv_delete;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there a way to figure out which activity called the adapter (in
>   the adapter class )

Yes of course. Simple thing is to send an additional parameter from the Adapter constructor and find out which class calls it. Create a String field.

```
String className;
```

And in the constructor:

```
    public Db_adapter(Context mContext, List<db_list> mDataList, String className) {
    //make a field and assign it with className
this.className = className
    }
```

And while either showing or hiding,

```
if(className.equals("ClassA")){
//hide something
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else if(className.equals("ClassB")){
//show something
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you said let us assume that I have two activities ActivityOne and ActivityTwo

```
Context context;
List<db_list> mDataList;

public Db_adapter(Context context, List<db_list> mDataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
}
```

And in your method you can do it like this

```
if(context instanceof ActivityOne) {
    // setVisibility
} else if(context instanceof ActivityTwo) {
    // setVisibility
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another constructor adding one more `boolean` value and store it in a variable in adapter like following:

```
boolean flag;    

public Db_adapter(Context mContext, List<db_list> mDataList,boolean anotherAcivityFlag) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
    flag = anotherAcivityFlag;
    this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)     mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public Db_adapter(Context mContext, List<db_list> mDataList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDataList = mDataList;
    flag = false;
    this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)     mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Add a if statement in getView() to detect what views you want to load.

Now initialize adapter with constructor to differentiate bw activities.

Comment: A simple alteration of my answer. Works fine if there is only choice of two classes.

Comment: you are right but then it becomes more specific you can not use it with same class. Abhay Kumar is illustrating his problem in a particular case but why to make a specific if it is possible with some generalized and can be reused in other use cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mContext. 
It is valorized that the time the Adapter is instantiated.
It is the Activity that created it.
So you can use whatever method you prefer having the Activity object handy.